# Angular 2 , month and year only needed in datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular2-forms, angular-date-format

i need the date to be pass like this 2018-03
using BsDatepickerModule of ngx-bootstrap,

i have got the result like this
2018-03-04
by using the code

```
......
self.dateSales = dateofSales.toISOString().split('T')[0];
.......
```

Help me to covert the date to yyyy-mm and yyyy format

Answer (score 0):

Is `dateinputformat` ok for you? Try this:

```
  <input
    class="form-control"
    [minDate]="minDate"
    [maxDate]="maxDate"
    #dp="bsDatepicker"
    bsDatepicker
    formControlName="myDate"
    [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM' }"
  >
```

Alternatively, if you want to format output, you can use what you have or you can use something like this:

```
const formattedDate = `${dateofSales.getFullYear()}-${dateOfSales.getMonth() < 9 '0' : ''}${(dateOfSales.getMonth() + 1)}`;
```

Or a bit more verbose:

```
const YYYY = `${date.getFullYear()}`;
let MM = `${date.getMonth() + 1}`;
if (MM.length < 2) MM = `0${MM}`;
const formattedDate = `${YYYY}-${MM}`;
```